# Spring data JPA entity graphs not working as expected when sort params are involved

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I have overridden `findAll` method in my repository to have an entitygraph that loads all the relations eagerly like below(we use querydsl support):

```
@EntityGraph(value = Group.GROUP_LOAD_ALL_ATTRIBUTES_EAGERLY, type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    Page<Group> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
```

My normal list all query without sort params working fine and sending a single join statement to the database(which is what I expected). However when I send sort params then it is doing multiple db queries(almost as many queries as there are records) instead of adding the sort criteria to the same join query.

Any clues why this is happening?